# pending intent is cancelled if app is updated?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

My app is not released yet but when testing I'm finding that if I have a notification active it seems to be cancelled if I update the app to test new features/code changes.

My app has notifications the user can customize so if these are cancelled upon an update it could be perceived pretty badly, is there a way around this or is this not a problem when an update is released?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops! I figured out my problem so the above question is now irrelevant.

Comment: if it is irrelevant than please delete the question or post the steps or solution that you got for your problem